# How do I setup a monit script to check if a directory exists and create it if it doesn't

Tags: monitoring, monit, mkdir

In the monit documentation I can see there is a check directory command but I can't see any examples of how to use it to see if the directory exists and if it doesn't to create the directory using the mkdir command.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
check directory my_path path /mnt/some_mount_point
  if does not exist then exec "/usr/local/bin/create_mnt.sh"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you `mkdir -p $directory` should do what you want. The `-p` option will create any necessary parent directories. If `$directory` already exists as a directory, the command does nothing, and succeeds. If $directory is a regular file, it will remain untouched, nd does not fail if the directory already exists, so you can do it all at once with:

> mkdir -p /some/directory/you/want/to/exist || exit 1

Answer (score 0):

Alec pretty much has it, but you don't need to create a script to do this. You can run `mkdir` directly (though note you need the full path to it):

```
check directory my_path path /mnt/some_mount_point
  if does not exist then exec "/bin/mkdir /mnt/some_mount_point"
```

Depending on your path, it may help to add the `-p` switch to mkdir if you need subfolders and/or duplicate error suppression.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create separate script, you need to use `bash` with `-c` option:

```
check directory my_path path /some/path/to/dir
  if does not exist then exec "/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /some/path/to/dir'"
  as uid <some_user> and gid <some_group>
```

The `monit` process is run from the root user, so make sure you are not creating directories as root (supposedly you don't need that)
And then you can kill `monit` process and start it in foreground with

```
monit -Ivv
```

and see output debug notes. Once there are not errors you can stop `monit` in foreground with C-c and start it as usual deamon process.

Hope this helps.